# Can I apply word-casing to a string using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to convert an all-uppercase string into a string where only the first letter of each word is in upper case using regular expressions?

> THIS IS A SAMPLE STRING  `--->` This Is A Sample String

At first I thought this would be an easy task, but now I don't even know how to start or even if it is possible.

Comment: No particular language. I need this for a custom application where the only way to transform a text is through regular expressions. (with Perl extensions to be precise)

Comment: Regexps are symbol acceptors, they are only used to match strings.  You really need to specify what kind of "replace" you are referring to.  A replace operation has a "match" step (i.e. the regexp+flags) and a substitution step (i.e. the replacement expression).  Depending on the implementation, the replacement expression can contain group references (e.g. $1) and other type of operations (e.g. "retain-case", "to-uppercase")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl:

```
$string =~ s/([\w']+)/\u\L$1/g;
```

(taken from the Perl FAQ)

Answer (score 1):

No, in most languages you can't use regular expressions to do that. An exception to this is [Perl](http://www.davekb.com/browse_programming_tips:perl_title_case:txt) which has a particularly powerful "regular" expression syntax.

You will probably find that your language has a library function that can do it. Look for something like `s.titlecase()`.

Related:

- [Format string to title case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746/format-string-to-title-case)